# Any analog of BroadcastReceivers in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, events, broadcastreceiver, subscribe

On Android, to listen to system-wide events like when WiFi has been turned on/off, location has changed, device is now in roaming and many other - one subscribes to these events using BroadcastReceivers.

What technique is used for similar purposes in iOS? Are there at all such global events about which the OS can notify cusom 3d-party apps?

I am new to iOS and haven't found anything in the docs, probably I just don't know the right keywords to look for.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> An NSNotificationCenter object (or simply, notification center)
>   provides a mechanism for broadcasting information within a program. An
>   NSNotificationCenter object is essentially a notification dispatch
>   table.

See full article - [Notification Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html)

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no lists of available notifications in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

NsNotificationcenter object is helpful within  the program or your application, if you want to listen for the events which happens outside your application then you can use NSDistributedNotificationCenter. 
check the below link. this may help you out.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsnotificationcenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html